# Does Fused Location Provider not work without wifi or is it just less accurate?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I read in this document the following [...]"Google introduced its Fused Location
Provider (FLP) [42]; however, these techniques depend on Wi-Fi for fine-grained results, which is not always available." 
source: www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/15/9/22060/pdf

From what I understand, high accuracy using fused location provider requires wifi but what about when it's not available? does it not work at all or does it provide less accurate results than when wifi is on ? And if it does work then does it automatically switch from fine location to coarse location?

Answer (score 0):

`FusedLocation` provider does work without wifi but keeping `Wifi` in ON state makes it more accurate. I have used it one of my apps which does not require `Wifi`.